# nancyfx compression on static content?

Tags: nancy

I am trying to work out how to enable compression on static content. I have a method similar to
http://romikoderbynew.com/2014/09/04/nancy-rest-services-gzip-it/

When you add a line like below to the ConfigureConventions in the bootstrap
`nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("Content", @"Content"));` and wire up a the compression code to `pipelines.AfterRequest`, any static content does not seem to go through the after request hook.

Is there anyway the static content can go through the pipeline so I can decide if i want to compress?

Answer (score 2):

Static content doesn't go through the pipeline. You'll have to replace the "Content" convention handler with your own that does compression.

If there are only a handful of files, you can place them in a different folder and handle them in a separate module using standard Nancy routing. Then it will go through your pipeline handlers.